# Using windows NTFS hard drives with Ubuntu

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, usb

Initially i had `Window 7` `3 internal SATA Drives 3TB` and 2 external SATA enclosures with 4 drives each enclosure.

Today morning i had the worst virus / randomware which encrypted  my 50% of stuff 10TB on all drives with some public key. I have no idea how it came/. I had Anti Virues  and Malwarebytes Antimalware but no one detected that. I disabled it from starup in safe mode and now i have to install all major software because every file in c drive is encrypted with some name-ID-karn@india.com.xtbl

I still have its setup file on desktop but nothing is  stll deteting it. All my C drives , D drive , E drives is encrypted and i have no way to recover it.

LUckily i had 30TB of data and it took and i noticed in morning and disconned all drives. Thank god it didn;t encrypted my backup drives.

So now i want to install Ubuntu desktop 16.04 as my main OS . I want to know that will my all drives can work as normal with ubuntu or i need to do something special on hard drives.  Can ubuntu auto detect the Enclosures HD drives as separate drives?

Also i had 2 graphics card and 4 monitors. will that work as it is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is a big ask - it can theoretically all be done under Linux, but might or might not be fiddly.

Under Linux, enclosures are typically seen as regular drives, and can be auto-detected.  You may need to ensure Linux has support for NTFS filesystems - but this is not hard - worst case you need to download some packages from the repository.   You do, however, need to be mindful that sometimes, if you take an internal drive - particularly a large one - and put it in an external enclosure, it may not be able to read the data on it because of different alignment of the sectors and 512k emulation on disks > 2tb.

The graphics card question is harder to answer - my guess is this will take quite a bit of hacking to get to work properly - if at all - and it will depend very much on the make of graphics card and acceleration/driver used.

Comment: I installed , all HD were auto detected , 3 monitors were auto detected but 4th one is not working. it says some CRTC error . another monitor of smae type and brand , model is detcted